# Reading the PUBLIC user photos and storing for displaying later - Graph API v2.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read the docs and I found that, I have to use the `user_photos` permission from the facebook user to read the photos from the user.

So after getting the permission, we could use access `me/photos/uploaded` to get the photos. The idea is to show the photos he/she has uploaded and allow them to choose the pics to store(the url) in my site's database.

Upon initiating the above Graph API call, we would get a list of photos in JSON format. Each photo will have several fields, along with `id`(FB unique ID) and `source`(FB's CDN url of the image).

If I want to store the URL of the image, and to display later to the visitors of my site, I have to store this `source` url? I mean the cached image URL that FB CDN provides ? Another thing is, if I store this URL, will this URL be changing later? I mean is it like a cached image for a particular time frame or something?